# How can we call functions in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In webforms, we do things like:

```
<%# CallSomefunctions(Eval("CustId")) %>
```

This function is present in asp.cs which can format our data and return appropriate string. How can we do the same in asp.net mvc since we do not have any concept of code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: You don't.  Doing this violates the principles of MVC.  The responsibility of your `.aspx` page it to convert a model (some .NET object) into something you can present to the user *and nothing else.*  Having it execute code violates this one-responsibility principle.

Comment: So what are the options? Say, I have a list of customers index method in controller and I want to display age from the birthdate. How do I do that? If I am correct you mean to say create a partial class of the model and then do Math stuff there. Am I correct?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly: Yes. The controller returns an `IEnumerable<Customer>` (or whatever), sorted in whatever way you want.  The view then transforms that collection of objects into HTML.